# Alignment of the image on another image css angularjs

Tags: html, css

I am new to angularjs and html css. I am creating app for 1st time in the app there is one list and the row of the list needs to have following:

1. Background Image (kind of banner image) --- coming from server api
2. Grey image Strip at bottom of the row above backgroundImage. ---static for all row placed at bottom.
3. Title for that row content. ---- The Title will be on the grey image strip
4. Short Description of that row content.--- The desc will be on the grey image strip

The problem is the grey image strip is not getting aligned properly when i check on the chrome it show properly when i check on firefox the alignment gets screwed.

As the application is made for mobile devices the UI needs to be responsive.

How can i make the grey image strip responsive.

Following is the demo image of how the row should look.
The 1st section mentioned in image is the banner image which will be placed on background.
2nd section is the grey strip image which will be placed at bottom and will contain title and desc text on it.

The grey strip image is not getting aligned properly in responsive environment.
[image]

Following is the code for the gray strip and the banner image.

```
<ul ng-repeat = "images in temples" style = "list-style: none; margin-left : 0%">
<li><img src= "{{images}}" ng-click="showTempleDetails('/templeDetails',$index)" style="position:relative">
<img src="img/transparentbgstrip.png">
</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking but: 1. use `ng-src=images` instead of `{{images}}`, 2. why don't you put the grey line with css?, and lastly, why would you say `images in temples` the current iteration variable is in plural. I suggest you name things in a clear way, like `temple in temples`. and you have a  closing div`</div>` without opening it.

Comment: the div opened just above the ul when i hard code the values of margin- bottom or bottom for the second one, the whole image looks great in CHROME, not so good in FIREFOX and in firefox responsive it overlaps in the center of the image PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parent element RELATIVE and whatever you want to place over that image as ABSOLUTE
then make this change in the above code

Make ul tag RELATIVE

and the strip image ABSOLUTE and add this

left:0px;
bottom:0px;